# Ruby map function for "pig latin"

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to write a ruby function that takes in a string of words and turns it into **[Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin)**. I am breaking the string into an array, and attempting to iterate over each element. When "eat pie" is put in, the result is "eat ie", but I am unsure why.

```
string = "eat pie"    
array = string.split(" ")

array.map do |word| 

 if word[0].chr == "a" || word[0].chr == "e" || word[0].chr == "i" || word[0].chr == "o" || word[0].chr == "u"

   word = word + "ay"

 elsif word[1].chr == "a" || word[1].chr == "i" || word[1].chr == "o" || word[1].chr == "u"
  temp = word[0]
  word[0] = ""
  word = word + temp
  word = word + "ay"

elsif word[2].chr == "a" || word[2].chr == "i" || word[2].chr == "o" || word[2].chr == "u"
  temp = word[0] + word[1]
  word[0] = ""
  word[0] = ""
  word = word + temp 
  word = word + "ay"

else ## three consonants
  temp = word[0] + word[1] + word[2]
  word[0] = ""
  word[0] = ""
  word[0] = ""
  word = word + temp 
  word = word + "ay"

 end ## end of if statement

end ## end of iteration 

puts array.join(" ")
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: FWIW `gsub` instead would save you from having to do `split` and then `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with the other answers supplied, here's a slightly less verbose version of your code in case it helps you.

```
input = 'pig latin is awesome'

arr = input.split(' ').map do |wrd|
    if %w(a e i o u).include? wrd[0]
      wrd + 'ay'
    elsif %w(a i o u).include? wrd[1]
      wrd[1..-1] + wrd[0] + 'ay'
    elsif %w(a i o u).include? wrd[2]
      wrd[2..-1] + wrd[0] + wrd[1] + 'ay'
    else
      wrd[3..-1] + wrd[0] + wrd[1] + wrd[2] + 'ay'
    end
end.join(' ')

puts arr
```

Comment: It's not intended to be a full or complete solution, more of a guide for the OP in shortening their work by highlighting other ways of handling it.

Answer (score 2):

The output you are seeing has 2 different causes:

1) In Ruby, `Array.map` returns a **new** array. It does not modify the array its iterating over. This is causing some of your modifications to the array to be lost.

From the [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

> Invokes the given block once for each element of self.
>   Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

You should either assign the result to a new variable, or use [`Array.map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) instead, which **will** modify the contents of the array.

```
array = string.split(" ")

mapped = array.map do |word| 
  # ...
end

mapped.join(" ")
```

2) Although some of your modifications are being lost due to using `map`, you are making modifications to some strings in your array, which is why you are seeing `eat ie`, and not `eat pie` (missing a `p`).

To illustrate this problem, look a the follow code:

```
word = "pie"
word[0] = ""

puts word #=> "ie"
```

In Ruby, when you access the first character in a string (by using `[0]`), and assign a value to it, Ruby **mutates** that string, and does not return a new copy.

You should create a new string, instead of changing characters directly:

```
array.map do |word|
  new_word = word.slice(1, word.length)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.map` does is not intended to mutate the array, so what you want to do is either `newarray = array.map { ... }` or `array.map! do ... end`.

Inside the loop, each `word` is a string object, that you are mutating by calling `word[0] = ""`. By calling `word = word + "ay"` you are discarding the reference of the original string, but not overwriting it. It happens though that `word = word + "ay"` is the last statement executed in the block so it counts as return value for the block.

I bet you are still confused because overall is not that simple so you might probably want to read something about *mutable* and *immutable* objects and *functional* and *imperative* programming.